# How to add wilcox_test results from rstatix to ggboxplot() using stat_pvalue_manual?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, ggpubr

I am trying to create a boxplot and manually add p-values to each comparison between boxplots:

```
    #I have the following boxplot
    ToothGrowth%>%ggplot(aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp))+
      geom_boxplot()

    #I would like to do a wilcoxon sum rank test on the data and label each comparison between OJ and VC
    stat.test <- ToothGrowth%>%group_by(dose)%>%wilcox_test(len~supp, p.adjust.method = 'BH')%>%
      mutate(y.position = c(29, 35, 39))
    stat.test
    #I try to add the p-values to my boxplots
    ToothGrowth%>%ggplot(aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp))+
      geom_boxplot()+
      stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = 'p')

    #However I get the following error:
    # Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'supp' not found
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! you've provided some useful details, but your question is still missing key information; please see SO's [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ways to improve your question and make it more practical for others to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `fill` argument in `geom_boxplot()` not in `ggplot()`.

Install the latest dev version of rstatix and ggpubr, then try the following R codes.

```
# Required packages
library(ggpubr)  # https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr
library(rstatix)  # https://github.com/kassambara/rstatix

# Stat test
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
stat.test <- ToothGrowth %>% 
  group_by(dose) %>% 
  wilcox_test(len~supp, p.adjust.method = 'BH') %>%
  mutate(y.position = c(29, 35, 39))
stat.test

# Plot + pvalue
bxp <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = dose, y = len)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = supp))
bxp + stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, x = "dose", label = 'p')
```

[image]

```
# Add automatically x and y positions
stat.test <- ToothGrowth %>% 
  group_by(dose) %>% 
  wilcox_test(len~supp, p.adjust.method = 'BH') %>%
  add_xy_position(x = "dose")
bxp + stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = 'p', tip.length = 0)
```

[image]